# Species that murder their own counterparts when put in captivity

Tags: ethology

Mary Midgley writes in her book, Beast and Man (p. 54 in this eBook: https://goo.gl/3NnhtP):

> Lorenz gives chilling examples from roe deer and doves, in both of which species stronger members will slowly murder weaker ones if kept in captivity with them[...]

I find this fascinating but I was not successful in finding any more info on this phenomena on the internet.

Can any biologists point me into a good direction? I do not have the work of Konrad Lorenz at hand, and would not know where to exactly look for in them.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Some individuals kill their own offspring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infanticide) or eat their offspring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filial_cannibalism) or their own siblings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siblicide).  See this article about siblicide and fratricide in bacteria:  https://www.webmedcentral.com/article_view/4804.

Other conflict and killing between members of a population occurs in many species, including humans (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homicide), mice (https://sci-hub.tw/10.1111/j.1469-185X.1991.tb01147.x), and other primates (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140175082920632).

Search "intraspecific killing" on Google or Google Scholar.

See also a similar question here:  [Why social animals attack odd members of their own group?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59081/why-social-animals-attack-odd-members-of-their-own-group?rq=1)